# Passing parameter using Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

I want to create a game which is basically ask your buddy to put a word. And you will guess what word has been entered. For that reason, I have to pass guesword from `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewController`.

First View Controller

```
- (IBAction)doneBtn:(id)sender {
    self.guessWord = [enterTF.text lowercaseString];
    NSLog (@"Guessword s %@", guessWord);
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    NSLog (@"%@", [segue identifier]);
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"F2S"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        SecondViewController *gvc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        gvc.guessWord =self.guessWord;
    }

}
```

Second View Controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"%@",guessWord);
}
```

In the `SecondViewController` guessword output "null". Why am I getting null?

[image]

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: Why am I getting null, instead of entered guessword

Comment: Why its null...kinda obvious

Comment: Does it hit that line that youre trying to pass it on??

Comment: yes, it hits that line.

Comment: And it isnt null when it hits that line?

Comment: whenever user enter guessword, it outputs in the firstviewcontroller. But whenever I look at guessword in secondviewcontroller, it is null

Comment: The segue, how does it get fired? It is attached to the button?, or do you call `performSegueWithIdentifier`?

Comment: Any chance that guessWord property is weak?

Comment: You have another problem with your storyboard. You should not go backwards from First and Second to ViewController using segues (unless you use an unwind segue). That will create a new instance of ViewController, and then when you go forward you will create new Firsts and Seconds thus adding more and more view controllers to your app. So, you either need to to use unwind segues, or don't use a segue, and use dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: in code to go back.

Answer (score 0):

In the second view controller, declare your variable in the .h file, say a string type:

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *someText;
```

Synthesize it in the .m file:

```
  @synthesize someText;
```

In the first view controller's segue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
NSLog (@"%@", [segue identifier]);
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"F2S"])
{
    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    SecondViewController *gvc = [segue destinationViewController];


    gvc.someText = **YOUR TEXT HERE** ; //this should set the value in the second view controller
}

}
```

If the passed value is not a string, change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sequence of events happening in your code:

1. The segue object is created. Source and destination view controllers are set on the segue, causing the second view controller to be loaded.
2. `-viewDidLoad:` is called on the second view controller.
3. `-prepareForSegue:` is called on the first view controller.
4. `-viewWillAppear:` and `-viewDidAppear:` are called on the second view controller.

`-viewDidLoad:` is called before `guessWord` is configured in `-prepareForSegue:`. Try `-viewWillAppear:` or `-viewDidAppear:` instead when logging `guessWord`.